# Background-image not showing?

Tags: images, css

Have been losing my mind over this for hours - background image isn't changing. It all works changing it in Chrome's devtools but for some reason when I implement it in the CSS stylesheet it reverts back to this:

Here is my current code:

```
.navbar-brand.logo-white {
  background-image: url("inc/img/logo@2x.png");
  background-size: 154px 31px; }
  @media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), all and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3 / 2), all and (min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), all and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
.navbar-brand.logo-white {
  background-image: url("inc/img/logo@2x.png"); } }
```

I've been changing the `.png` after

```
background-image: url
```

To an image link, eg:

```
background-image:url("http://www.website.com/image.png");
```

But it refuses to acknowledge those changes. I'm not at all familiar with PHP but I thought an image change would be a simple CSS fix.

Comment: Where are you implementing this custom CSS, in your child's theme? May you provide a link to your website with this background image?

Comment: Do you have a cache plugin installed on the site? If so clear that and see if that updates your css.

Comment: Hi there, sorry I wasn't able to provide more detail - the website wasn't to go live until this morning. The website in question is http://blog.sense.com, and I'm trying to change the "sense" logo at the top to the logo found in the header at http://sense.com.

Answer (score 0):

We lack context, but remember that CSS files are read from top to bottom, the lower definitions having priority over the top ones. The same logic applies within the file. That is why the `!important` attribute is used for.

That being said, in your case you could have

- A caching plugin that loads a cached copy of your CSS file.  Effectively ignoring your changes.
- A bottom rules overriding a top one.
- A conflicting css target definition.
- A bad css target definition.
- A narrower css attribute definition overrider a broader one.
- Something else I might not be thinking of right now

So check those things or provide us with better insight if nothing in that list fixes your issue.

Comment: Hi there, sorry I wasn't able to provide more detail - the website wasn't to go live until this morning. The website in question is http://blog.sense.com, and I'm trying to change the "sense" logo at the top to the logo found in the header at http://sense.com.